# Error POSTing File in Perl

Tags: forms, perl, post, request

im trying to rebuild a request (File upload), the packed send from the webbrowser looks like this:

```
-----------------------------596088922920
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="mypic.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

GIF87aX#  *shorted*  ¡§\
-----------------------------596088922920
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="session"

92384729384792384729384729384
-----------------------------596088922920
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="method"

put
-----------------------------596088922920--
```

my per code looks like this:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
$agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => {} );
  $agent->post('http://www.kleiderkreisel.de/photo/ajax_photo_action',
    [
        "Filedata" => ['mypic.gif' => 'C:\Pics\mypic.gif'],
        'session' => '92384729384792384729384729384',
        'method' => 'put'
    ]);
```

sadly this gives me the error "Internal Server Error"...
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`HTTP::Request::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common) (referenced from [`LWP::UserAgent->post`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS) which is referenced from [`WWW::Mechanize->post`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-post)) you must explicitly set the content-type to `form-data`. Thus the code should be:

```
$agent->post('http://www.kleiderkreisel.de/photo/ajax_photo_action',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content =>  [
        "Filedata" => ['mypic.gif' => 'C:\Pics\mypic.gif'],
        'session' => '92384729384792384729384729384',
        'method' => 'put'
    ]
);
```